# Why sDNA error is out of memory? Can it run in 64-bit?

Tags: sdna

[image: I use sDNA to prepare road network, but as in the pic, the error is out of memory, what can I do with it? and I notice that sDNA is running in 32-bit mode, can it run in 64-bit?]

I use sDNA to prepare road network, but as in the pic, the error is out of memory, what can I do with it? And I notice that sDNA is running in 32-bit mode, can it run in 64-bit?

Comment: A binary can be either 32-bit or 64-bit. You cannot run a 32-bit application in 64-bit mode or vice-versa.  A 64-bit application can also run out of memory, it just takes a bit longer.

Comment: sDNA has both 32 and 64 bit dlls which are loaded by ArcGIS, QGIS, command line scripts or whatever else. The entry point is a python script which loads the relevant dll depending on the bitness of the calling process - hence sDNA reporting that it runs in either 32 or 64 bit mode.

Answer (score 1):

A 32 bit application is inherently limited to using about 3.5GB of memory - with a network of half a million links it is possible you have run out.

If you enable 64 bit ArcGIS background processing (`geoprocessing -> options -> enable background processing`, I think) then sDNA will run in 64 bit mode instead, enabling you to use all the memory available on your machine. Check the output, as you already have, to check this works. In some versions of ArcGIS it will still run in 32 bit mode in the background - if this is the case you will need to install ArcGIS 64 bit background processing first - this is usually on your install disk but needs installing separately to ArcGIS.

(Unfortunately as you take this route you will find there is a bug in ArcGIS whereby although 64 bit background processes will run fine, you can't monitor progress! For this reason, with large networks you may prefer to use the QGIS interface - for which you would need to convert your data to shapefiles first - or the command line interface. See the sDNA manual for more details on either of these.)